# Why do I read 70 and 50 volts at a GFCI outlet?

Tags: gfci, tape

I've got two wires coming in from supply to what was a GFCI receptacle; a black and a white with black tape.  If I measure across one to ground, I get 70v, and the other, 50v.  There are two other outlets daisy-chained from this circuit.  So, one GFCI protecting two regular outlets.  Can anyone shed some light on what is going on here and how to wire it back? The original GFCI was working, but came apart inside the wall (no box) when I did some remodeling.

Here is a rudimentary diagram.

[image]

Comment: "came apart inside the wall (no box)" Are you saying that this outlet is not enclosed in an outlet box? If so, this must be remedied.

Comment: The "70V and 50V" problem may simply be phantom voltage, with proper (120V and 0V) when tested under load, so I'm not worried about *that* part. On 120V circuits with individual wires, there should never be "white marked black". On 120V circuits with cables (which I think is what you have), white can be marked black in certain specific situations, typically involving "switch loops". But that doesn't make sense here. Plus *most* GFCI use "top for line, bottom for load" in which case it would be "all wires from supply to top" and "all wires to next receptacle to bottom".  So...

Comment: Supply must be on right and left side and second outlet the same.  Your picture has supply on one side(right) and other outlet/s on other side(left).  White with black tape usually means hot(white white with power).

Comment: please upload pictures of **this "box"** and of the preceding "thing" (either another receptacle, a switch box or the breaker panel) and of the next "thing" (which is likely another receptacle). Something is very fishy...

Comment: Probably there is no ground in box. You measured voyages in reference to some wire, not connected anywhere.

Comment: What was there *before?* How are these wires grouped into cables? Can you identift the Line terminals and the Load terminals? (Physical position varies).

Comment: 1.  No.  There were NO boxes in the sheetrock.  I'm adding them.

Comment: The wires are "grouped" is in my representation.  The right side is in one Romex.  The left side is in the other Romex to the third outlet.  The outlet in the middle just had jumper wires from the GFCI to it, but as I said, everything came apart in the wall due to the demo.  Otherwise, would have took a photo if I new it was so different.

Comment: I'll do up another drawing and hopefully be able to add it to the primary post.

Comment: Okay, here's a better look.  I hope.  GFCI on rightmost outlet.  Regular outlets are the other two.  I know the second outlet was wired like this.  Like I said, everything came apart there were bare wires in the wall.  This is my best guess.  The white with black and see partial voltage is throwing me.

Comment: I'm not at home at the moment.  I will try to get a pick of the breaker panel later.

Comment: The taped white usually indicates a switch loop. Is this outlet inline with a light fixture?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be.  When I throw off the breaker, only the outlets are off in that bathroom.  All of the lights and fans still work.  I guess that doesn't rule out it being tied elsewhere, but I'd find it odd that GFCI bathroom outlets are in a switch loop, but then again, I'm not an electrician.

Comment: *The wires are "grouped" is in my representation. The right side is in one Romex. The left side is in the other Romex to the third outlet.* That's an unlikely configuration.  You need to look at the GFCI device to ascertain which terminals are LINE and which are LOAD.  Connect only 2 wires (from the same cable) only to LINE until you have a GFCI working.  Connecting anything to LOAD on a broken GFCI will do nothing but obfuscate.

Comment: If I saw a cable with a taped white wire, I would connect it to a plain receptacle, plug in a hair dryer, and expect a lamp to turn on when I turn on the hair dryer. That would be proof positive of a switch loop.  (the hair dryer serves only as a means to short-circuit the 2 wires, with a less catastrophic failure mode if I'm wrong).

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box this whole arrangement pulls power from?

Comment: Okay, folks.  Finally was able to get back to this.  I was mistaken.  The breaker DOES turn off the lights AND the receptacles in this bathroom.  So that white with black indeed must be a "switch loop," which was feeding a GFI wall receptacle, which is daisy-chained to another receptacle in the same box, and that second receptacle daisy-chains to a third receptacle on the other side of the bathroom.  3 receptacles in total. Somehow.